Pydantic wrapper error while invoking openai client on streamlit. Got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
I have a problem with an app on streamlit: On localhost it works perfectly, but on streamlit not. The funny thing is that the application was working, but after the code update I suddenly started getting this error. After reverting back to the original code before the changes, the previously working code returns the same error. I checked what parameters are passed to the ChatOpenAI function and there are no "proxies".
────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ───────────────────────
  /home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptru  
  nner/exec_code.py:88 in exec_func_with_error_handling                         
                                                                                
  /home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptru  
  nner/script_runner.py:579 in code_to_exec                                     
                                                                                
  /mount/src/langgraph_agent/app/app_st.py:212 in <module>                      
    209                                                                         
    210                                                                         
    211 if __name__ == "__main__":                                              
  ❱ 212 │   main()                                                              
    213                                                                         

....
....
....

  /mount/src/langgraph_agent/agents/agents.py:40 in get_llm                     

     37 │                                                                       
     38 │   def get_llm(self, json_model=True):                                 
     39 │   │   if self.server == 'openai':                                     
  ❱  40 │   │   │   return get_open_ai_json(model=self.model, temperature=self  
     41 │   │   if self.server == 'ollama':                                     
     42 │   │   │   return OllamaJSONModel(model=self.model, temperature=self.  
     43 │   │   if self.server == 'vllm':                                       

  /mount/src/langgraph_agent/models/openai_models.py:11 in get_open_ai          

     8                                                                          
     9 def get_open_ai(temperature=0, model='gpt-3.5-turbo'):                   
    10 │                                                                        
  ❱ 11 │   llm = ChatOpenAI(                                                    
    12 │   model=model,                                                         
    13 │   temperature = temperature,                                           
    14 )                                                                        

  /home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py:341 in  
  __init__                                                                      

     338 │   │   # Uses something other than `self` the first arg to allow "se  
     339 │   │   values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(__pydan  
     340 │   │   if validation_error:                                           
  ❱  341 │   │   │   raise validation_error                                     
     342 │   │   try:                                                           
     343 │   │   │   object_setattr(__pydantic_self__, '__dict__', values)      
     344 │   │   except TypeError as e:                                         
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
ValidationError: 1 validation error for ChatOpenAI
__root__
  Client.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies' 
(type=type_error)


restarting the app
checking the enviroment
checking if any package was updated in the meantime
checked for "proxies" variable as input in the function - not the case
restoring state of the app to the previous working code


Issue solved. don't use openai=1.55.2 version! update to 1.55.3.

Could you please write an answer and accept it in case you have resolved the issue? That would be helpful to others as well. Thanks!

pip install --force-reinstall -v “openai==1.55.3”


OpenAI version 1.55.2 contains a bug which is resolved in OpenAI version 1.55.3.
In Streamlit's case, edit the version in the requirements file.

I got the same error message with an older version of OpenAI (1.11.1). The issue was caused by recent changes in the httpx package.
Downgrading to httpx==0.27.0 fixed this for me.
